# Discord.py sending messages to members on join and giving them roles

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I wanted to make my bot send a direct message to people who join my server and give them role 30 seconds later.
I don't get any error, my bot don't crashes, but it just doesn't do anything.

**My code:**

```py
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    await member.send('Hi! Welcome to our server, in 30 seconds you will get "Verified" role, please read rules in that time.')
    time.sleep(30)
    await member.add_roles('Verified')
```

I've imported `discord`, `time` and my bot has permissions, member has no DMs blocked.

Comment: Does your bot add the role after 30 seconds as intended? Can you add a `print` statement when you test it to make sure the function is called?

Comment: No, it doesn't give, i can make `print` statement but i think it crashes on sending message. I try to check it

Comment: Ok, it doesn't detect new member.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the latest version of `discord.py`, this should work:

```py
@bot.event   #Event to detect when a user joins the server
async def on_member_join(member):
    await member.send('Hi! Welcome to our server, in 30 seconds you will get "Verified" role, please read rules in that time.')
    time.sleep(30)   #The parameter is in seconds, so it'll wait for 30 seconds
    verifiedRole = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, id = THE_ROLE_ID)
    await member.add_roles(verifiedRole)
```

**Note:** Keep in mind that the bot will stop working for these 30 seconds. So using `time.sleep()` **terrible** idea. Use `asyncio.sleep()` instead.

```py
@bot.event   #Event to detect when a user joins the server
async def on_member_join(member):
    await member.send('Hi! Welcome to our server, in 30 seconds you will get "Verified" role, please read rules in that time.')
    await asyncio.sleep(30)   #The parameter is in seconds, so it'll wait for 30 seconds
    verifiedRole = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, id = THE_ROLE_ID)
    await member.add_roles(verifiedRole)
```

By using this one, the bot will still be functional in these 30 seconds. Remember to import `asyncio` instead of `time`.

---

Replace `THE_ROLE_ID` with the role ID from the server which you can obtain by *right-clicking* a role as shown below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To get the [member join event](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_member_join), your bot need [members intent](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Intents.members), which is disabled by default. To get it you have to do two things:

Go to the developer portal and under 'bot' ==> 'Privileged Gateway Intents' toggle 'SERVER MEMBERS INTENT' to be on.

Enable it in your bot, like:

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

bot = commands.Bot(intents=intents, ...) # command_prefix and other things like that in the ...
```

Comment: I got this error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bot.py", line 5, in <module>
    intents = discord.Intents.default()
AttributeError: module 'discord' has no attribute 'Intents'`